# How useful are old textbooks on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for resources to get my 1Z0-071 certification but Oracle wants a subscription fee of 5000 USD and there's tons of Udemy courses but let's say I go to a library and find an old book from 2010, would it still be relatively useful for learning the necessary material? I got started on SQL off of Udemy but only for generalized material. Any takes would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd also say that most of SQL and PL/SQL hasn't changed in the past 20 years or so. New features have been added, and only for those you need to look in fresh documentation. But you may also learn from the online documentation on the Oracle site, which I've been doing for years. In 2010 you have all the object extensions of PL/SQL and object types in the database  also and pipelined functions also. You do not have default on conversion error for conversion functions (that was a real pain!) and the possibility that pipelined functions pipe types declared in a package specification

Comment: Oracle price gouging.... wow what a suprise.

Answer (score 3):

This is [Oracle Database SQL - Exam Number: 1Z0-071](https://education.oracle.com/oracle-database-sql/pexam_1Z0-071) page which is currently valid.

Reviewing exam topics chapter, I'd say that vast majority of subjects existed back in 1995, so - yes, I'd say that a book that dates in 2010 would do for **this exam**.

True, things have changed since Oracle 11g (R2 was released in 2009), but `SELECT` statement works as it used to, column aliases are still here, we use `order by` to sort data, `to_char` function is here, subqueries as well ... therefore, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a 13 year old textbook to prepare for Oracle SQL exam 1Z0-071 would work fine.

The basic features of Oracle SQL have not significantly changed for a long time. The same was true when I took one of Oracle's SQL exams in 2012. And based on [the list of topics for the exam](https://education.oracle.com/oracle-database-sql/pexam_1Z0-071), I doubt any of these "fundamental SQL concepts" require up-to-date information.

---

Note that my advice only applies to the narrow conditions of this question, and I am not recommending a specific book. A programming textbook from 2010 would likely *not* be sufficient for an exam about database administration (where fundamental features like container databases have changed), or an exam about advanced features (which use newer features), or an exam about other programming languages. While most book recommendation questions are too opinionated for Stack Overflow, this question has a relatively simple, objective answer.